# Where is phpmyadmin located in plesk?

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, plesk, locate

I have plesk 8.3.0, with phpmyadmin 2.8.2.4
I tried to look up where the phpmyadmin is located.  I couldn't find it in srv/  and i did a find command in the server and not quite sure where it is actually located.

What I want to do is to set up a phpmyadmin under /httpdocs  so that I dont have to login to plesk and click many times until i can launch phpmyadmin..

Any idea?  thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This may vary for different Plesk versions.

Phpmyadmin is in `/usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/` on mine.

Comment: You should add which plesk version you have. In my case 18.0.31 path is /usr/local/psa/phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @AlecTMH it may vary between versions of Plesk. His answer was fine for me before but now, after having done some updates to Plesk (am currently on version 18.0.31 Obsidian), I had to do a bit of searching on my drive to locate it, it is now here: `/opt/psa/phpMyAdmin` .

And since I also have my own version of **phpmyadmin** installed on one of my domains besides the one included in plesk, so that I can access it directly without going through the plesk panel, I had to exclude those paths in my search in order to locate the plesk version:

```
locate -i phpmyadmin | grep -P '(?<!/var/www/vhosts/myvps.ovh.net/httpdocs/)(?<!/var/www/vhosts/myvps.ovh.net/httpdocs/phpmyadmin/vendor/)phpmyadmin'
```

Comment: The location of Plesk phpmyAdmin is nano /opt/psa/phpMyAdmin/config.plesk.php
"Variable 'lc_messages' can't be set to the value of en_EN" 
Solution: $cfg['Lang'] = 'en';

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really familiar with Plesk, but I've used hosts that had a roundabout way to getting to phpMyAdmin. I've always just clicked around until it launched phpMyAdmin, then bookmarked that page so I didn't have to bother remembering the arbitrary address. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: thanks.  but for my situation, bookmark won't work. it redirect back to plesk.